# Regular Expression format for 0000/123456/23

Tags: asp.net

I have a text box for Registration Number and i want it to use the following format 2013/123456/25. I want to validate for in-correct format using Regular Expression Validator.

The exact format must be first 4 numbers/6 numbers/2 numbers -->(2013/123456/25)

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this :

`^\d{4}/\d{6}/\d{2}$`